# Set return value as environment variable

Tags: paw-app

I would like to set the return value of an auth call (a token) as an environment variable so that other calls can make use of the value and I don't have to change that value manually.

Can Paw already do this easily?

If not, how would I lay out an extension to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best is that you set your OAuth dynamic value in your header field, then copy the value (select the text and hit Cmd + C):

[image]

Go to edit your environments and paste the dynamic value (Cmd + V) in a new variable:

[image]

Now go back to your header, and start to write the name of the environment variable you just created, it will offer you to use this variable:

[image]

You should be good to go now:

[image]

If later you need a change in your token, you can go back to the environments and edit it there, all at the same place.

Comment: Rereading my question, I wasn't clear: I actually wanted to avoid having to go and edit the environment variable manually every time I authenticate. Is there any clever way to automate this process? :)

Comment: No, that's the only way for now. You can save time by having the environment window always open: in the Window menu > Prefer Panels over Sheets.